# Push_Front Pop_Back for C++ Vector

Tags: c++, vector

I'm trying to keep a vector of commands so that it keeps 10 most recent.  I have a push_back and a pop_back, but how do I delete the oldest without shifting everything in a for loop?  Is erase the only way to do this?

Comment: Maybe use a `std:deque`?

Comment: You just drop out `std::vector::first()` whenever the size will grow bigger than 10?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ won't that violate the "no shifts" req of the OP?

Comment: `erase`, but `std::vector` does the shifting for you. Use `std::queue`. It's built for this sort of thing.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`std::deque`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque) which is a vector-like container that's good at removal and insertion at both ends.

Answer (score 3):

If you're amenable to using boost, I'd recommend looking at [`circular_buffer`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/doc/html/circular_buffer/example.html), which deals with this exact problem extremely efficiently (it avoids moving elements around unnecessarily, and instead just manipulates a couple of pointers):

```
 // Create a circular buffer with a capacity for 3 integers.
 boost::circular_buffer<int> cb(3);

 // Insert threee elements into the buffer.
 cb.push_back(1);
 cb.push_back(2);
 cb.push_back(3);
 cb.push_back(4);
 cb.push_back(5);
```

The last two ops simply overwrite the elements of the first two.

Answer (score 2):

Write a wrapper around a vector to give yourself a circular buffer.  Something like this:

```
include <vector>

/**

  Circular vector wrapper

  When the vector is full, old data is overwritten

*/
class cCircularVector
{
public:

    // An iterator that points to the physical begining of the vector
    typedef std::vector< short >::iterator iterator;
    iterator begin() { return myVector.begin(); }
    iterator end() { return myVector.end(); }

    // The size ( capacity ) of the vector
    int size() { return (int) myVector.size(); }

    void clear() { myVector.clear(); next = 0; }

    void resize( int s ) { myVector.resize( s ); }

    // Constructor, specifying the capacity
    cCircularVector( int capacity )
    : next( 0 )
    {
        myVector.resize( capacity );
    }

    // Add new data, over-writing oldest if full
    void push_back( short v )
    {
        myVector[ next] = v;
        advance();
    }

    int getNext()
    {
        return next;
    }

private:

    std::vector< short > myVector;
    int next;

    void advance()
    {
        next++;
        if( next == (int)myVector.size() )
            next = 0;

    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

What about something like this:

http://ideone.com/SLSNpc

Note: It's just a base, you still need to work a bit on it. The idea is that it's easy to use because it has it's own iterator, which will give you the output you want. As you can see the last value inserted is the one shown first, which I'm guessing is what you want.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template<class T, size_t MaxSize>
class TopN
{
public:
    void push_back(T v)
    {
        if (m_vector.size() < MaxSize)
            m_vector.push_back(v);
        else
            m_vector[m_pos] = v;

        if (++m_pos == MaxSize)
            m_pos = 0;
    }

    class DummyIterator
    {
    public:
        TopN &r; // a direct reference to our boss.
        int p, m; // m: how many elements we can pull from vector, p: position of the cursor.

        DummyIterator(TopN& t) : r(t), p(t.m_pos), m(t.m_vector.size()){}

        operator bool() const { return (m > 0); }

        T& operator *()
        {
            static T e = 0; // this could be removed
            if (m <= 0) // if someone tries to extract data from an empty vector
                return e; // instead of throwing an error, we return a dummy value

            m--;

            if (--p < 0)
                p = MaxSize - 1;

            return r.m_vector[p];
        }
    };

    decltype(auto) begin() { return m_vector.begin(); }
    decltype(auto) end() { return m_vector.end(); }

    DummyIterator get_dummy_iterator()
    {
        return DummyIterator(*this);
    }
private:
    std::vector<T> m_vector;
    int m_pos = 0;
};

template<typename T, size_t S>
void show(TopN<T,S>& t)
{
    for (auto it = t.get_dummy_iterator(); it; )
        std::cout << *it << '\t';

    std::cout << std::endl;
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    TopN<int,10> top10;
    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
        top10.push_back(5 * i);

    show(top10);

    top10.push_back(60);
    show(top10);

    top10.push_back(65);
    show(top10);

    return 0;
}
```